# How to select dataframes that only have 6 columns from a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a list of dataframes varying in columns. I want to select only the dataframes that have specifically 6 columns only and concatenate.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list, columns=['0'])
```

This gives me a column from every dataframe in the list..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
l = [df for df in dfs if df.columns.size == 6]
```

Then

```
pd.concat(l)
```